# The set $X=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\;;\;a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\;;\;a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, show that elements of $X$ is unique.

**My attempt** : I thought of considering the elements $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2}\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a_{1}+b_{1}\sqrt{2}=a_{2}+b_{2}\sqrt{2}$, to show that $a_{1}=a_{2}$ and $b_{1}=b_{2}$. However, I am stuck here and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Duplicate isn't it ?

Comment: can you please show us your attempt? Moreover this is a duplicate question

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: Just an annoying pedantic note, the elements of a set are always unique. What you are trying to show is that each element has a unique representation of the form shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a_1-a_2=(b_2-b_1)\sqrt{2}$. If $b_1\ne b_2$ then this implies $\sqrt{2}=\frac{a_1-a_2}{b_2-b_1}\in\mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction. So we must have $b_1=b_2$. And this also implies $a_1=a_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I will accept your answer in a moment